# What kinetic model does the hydrogenation reaction of dibenzyltoluene follow?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, physical-organic-chemistry

So during the course of my research, I've read countless papers related to the hydrogenation of dibenzyltoluenen and the dehydrogenation of perhydro-dibenzyltoluene. Now what I've noticed, is the fact that I could not find any data concerning the kinetic models linked to this hydrogenation process (I did find kinetic data concerning dehydrogenation of perhydro-dibenzyltoluene).

Is there a specific reason for this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of hydrogenation?